# How to set up onClick for a canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have been developing a simple android application where circles will be bouncing around on the screen. I would now like to add an onClick, or onClickListener so that users can interact with the images. Being fairly new to android development, I have no idea how to do this.

Can someone lend me a helping hand?

Here's most of the code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Circle> circles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    class MyView extends View {

        public Paint p;
        private int w, h;

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p = new Paint();
            circles = new ArrayList<>();
            circles.add(new Circle(100, Color.GREEN, 150, 200, 8, 8));
            circles.add(new Circle(200, Color.BLUE, 500, 500, 4, 7));
            circles.add(new Circle(70, Color.RED, 1000, 750, 20, 12));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            this.w = w;
            this.h = h;
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }



        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            // Drawing circles using loop and canvas.drawCircle()

            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on onTouchEvent

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      }
}
```

- **MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN** New touch started

  **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** Finger is moving

  **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP** Finger went up

  **MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL** Current event has been canceled, something
  else took control of the touch event

  **MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN** Pointer down (multi-touch)

  **MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP** Pointer up (multi-touch)